# Excluding optional sub-dependency from Android library published to Maven Central

Tags: android, gradle, maven-central

I am building an Android library that depends on PayPal Android SDK.
I am trying to exclude card.io credit card scanning from the PayPal SDK.

```
compile('com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.13.3') {
    exclude group: 'io.card'
}
```

The problem is, when I push my library to Maven Central, and include it in example project,
card.io native libraries are included in the build anyway, and they increase the apk size by ~11 megabytes.

I have tried adding this to my build.gradle

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libcardioDecider.so'
    exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libcardioRecognizer.so'
    exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libcardioRecognizer_tegra2.so'
    exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libopencv_core.so'
    exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libopencv_imgproc.so'
    exclude 'lib/armeabi/libcardioDecider.so'
    exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libcardioDecider.so'
    exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libcardioRecognizer.so'
    exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libcardioRecognizer_tegra2.so'
    exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.so'
    exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_imgproc.so'
    exclude 'lib/mips/libcardioDecider.so'
    exclude 'lib/x86/libcardioDecider.so'
    exclude 'lib/x86/libcardioRecognizer.so'
    exclude 'lib/x86/libcardioRecognizer_tegra2.so'
    exclude 'lib/x86/libopencv_core.so'
    exclude 'lib/x86/libopencv_imgproc.so'
    exclude 'lib/x86_64/libcardioDecider.so'
    exclude 'lib/x86_64/libcardioRecognizer.so'
    exclude 'lib/x86_64/libcardioRecognizer_tegra2.so'
    exclude 'lib/x86_64/libopencv_core.so'
    exclude 'lib/x86_64/libopencv_imgproc.so'
}
```

but it only works when I add it to example app's build.gradle, not to my lib's build.gradle.
I would like to avoid users of my lib having to add this to their app's build.gradle.

A bit more details:
I am not actually pushing the library to maven central right away.
I am pushing it to a staging repository at oss.sonatype.org and pulling it from there using this:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/staging/"
    }
}
```

When I manually look at the .pom file from the repo, I am not seeing any exclusions added for the PayPal dependency.
I tried excluding both group 'io.card' and module 'android-sdk' from PayPal dependency, and then the exclusion DOES show in the .pom file,
but the card.io native libraries are still included in the final build.

I am clearing gradle cache after creating repositories to make sure it always downloads the latest version of my SDK from the staging repo.

One ugly solution that works is to add `exclude group: 'io.card'` when including my library, but I would like to avoid that.